# Connection closing abruptly

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I am working on a Java program which will get the total row count of all the tables in source end and destination end for data count validation.
At the moment, I have written code to get the count from Source tables.
Below is the connection class:

```
public static Connection getGpConnection() {
        try {
            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
            if(gpConnection == null) {
                gpConnection = DriverManager.getConnection("hostname", "username", "password");
                return gpConnection;
            } else {
            return gpConnection;
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Method that gets the row count of all the source tables:

```
public Map<String,Long> getGpTableCount() throws SQLException {
        Map<String, String> gpTableMap = getScopeTableList();
        Set<String> gpTableSet = gpTableMap.keySet();
        gpCountMap = new HashMap<String, Long>();
        Iterator<String> keySetIterator_gpTables = gpTableSet.iterator();
        Connection gpAnalyticsCon = (Connection) DbManager.getGpConnection();
        while(keySetIterator_gpTables.hasNext()) {
            String gpSchemaTableName = keySetIterator_gpTables.next();  // Ex: schema.tablename
            String[] gpparts = gpSchemaTableName.split("\\.");  // schema, tablename
            String gpTable = gpparts[1];
            String gpCountQuery = "select '" + gpTable + "' as TableName, count(*) as Count, source_system_name from " + gpSchemaTableName + " group by source_system_name order by source_system_name limit 30";
            // resultSet(1): TableName, resultSet(2): count, resultSet(3): source_system_name
            try {
                gpAnalyticsCon.setAutoCommit(false);
                PreparedStatement gp_pstmnt = gpAnalyticsCon.prepareStatement(gpCountQuery);
                ResultSet gpCountRs = gp_pstmnt.executeQuery();
                while(gpCountRs.next()) {
                    gpCountMap.put(gpTable + ": " + gpCountRs.getString(3), gpCountRs.getLong(2));
                }
            } catch(SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if(gpAnalyticsCon != null) {
                //  gpAnalyticsCon.setAutoCommit(true);
                    gpAnalyticsCon.commit();
                    System.out.println("Closing the connection: Divya");
                    gpAnalyticsCon.close();
                }
            }
        }
        return gpCountMap;
    }
```

The problem is, after it executes for one table in all the source systems, the connection closes with the following exception:

```
Tablename: table1 Source System Name: source1, Count: 4
Tablename: table1 Source System Name: source2, Count: 9
Tablename: table1 Source System Name: source3, Count: 1
Tablename: table1 Source System Name: source4, Count: 88
Tablename: table1 Source System Name: source5, Count: 15
Tablename: table1 Source System Name: source6, Count: 2
Tablename: table1 Source System Name: source7, Count: 1521
Tablename: table1 Source System Name: source8, Count: 1288
Tablename: table1 Source System Name: source9, Count: 24569
Exception in thread "main" org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Cannot commit when autoCommit is enabled.
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.commit(PgConnection.java:756)
    at com.recordcount.dao.GpHiveRecords.getGpTableCount(GpHiveRecords.java:82)
    at com.recordcount.entry.StartCount.main(StartCount.java:12)
```

I understand I am using the connection wrongly, but I could identify the mistake.
Can anyone let me know what is the mistake I am doing here.

Comment: why do you set `autoCommit` at `true` and then manually commit?

Comment: Also, what are you commiting?

Comment: I was trying to commit by using setAutoCommit(true). But it was also giving an exception. Hence I used con.commit() line. But I forgot to comment the line // setAutoCommit(true) while pasting here.I had a println statement there to see the flow of program.  I have update the question.

Comment: Your connection is also being closed after the first iteration of the outer loop so the next iteration of the outer loop (assuming there is one) will throw an exception.  A couple of other friendly suggestions: use a [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) if possible, and maybe re-examine your exception handling.

Comment: Given your edit to comment out the `gpAnalyticsCon.setAutoCommit(true)`, you should no longer get the above exception, and if you do, then the code shown is not the code you are executing.

Comment: I have commented all the commit related statements and the finally block, moved the connection.close statement just before the return statement and the code is working.